# Where does this probability integration magically come from?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For the problem 2 of this [PDF](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn05.pdf), the [solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn05_sol.pdf) given states that:

[image: img]

My question is where does probability integration magically come from and integrate nicely to $1$?

Comment: Since it's a probability density function, its integral (over its domain) is 1 by definition. The point is then that, since this is linear, you know it's of the form $ax$ for some a. You also know the domain of definition, so what's happening here is they're determining the $a$ that makes this a pdf - i.e. that makes this integral 1.

Comment: So that one is the marginal probability?